# Android 5.0 MediaPlayer error in VideoView (1, -38)

Tags: android, prepared-statement, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I get the error E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38) when starting a video on android 5.0 API 21.
it works on every other Android version. 
this is how i start the video

```
mVideo.setVideoPath(mVideoPaths.get(mIndex));
mVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    android.util.Log.e("onPrepared: ", "prepped");
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
videoUrl= java.net.URLDecoder.decode(videoUrl, "UTF-8");
Uri video = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
```

You can also use Third-party libraries available in Github under open source liscence.
Here one one example : https://github.com/amoussawi/ITEC-MediaPlayer

This library is an excellent replacement for Android Mediaplayer or VideoView. This has many features like seeking, playback speed adjustment, zooming etc..

Comment: thank you for your response, but i need min api 14.. so i cant use this library. 
and parsing the videopath and setting it as uri doesnst help either

Comment: this one also requires min api 16

Comment: supporting for Min API 14 means Your supporting Android IceCream sandwitch devices. Google already dropped support for these devices. only few devices running in these version of android. better to support from Android jellybean +.

Comment: yeah thats true, but sadly i am not able to change the api version